# C++ SpellChecker Library

Tags: c++, open-source, spell-checking

Can anybody recommend a good (ideally open source) C++ spell checker library. We are currenly using Talo, which isn't very good, so we are looking to change.

One which includes a grammar checker would also be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard good things about [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/). I have used and integrated [aspell](http://aspell.net/), which has some nice features and some which I did not like.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got internet access, you can always use on online service like [SpellCheck.net](http://www.spellcheck.net) which has a CGI interface that you can query.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Yuval - [OpenOffice Lingucomponent](http://lingucomponent.openoffice.org/index.html)

Comment: Can this be used from C++ though?