# C++: check whether a word is spelled correctly

Tags: c++, spelling

I'm looking for an easy way to check whether a certain string is a correctly-spelled English word. For example, 'looked' would return True while 'hurrr' would return False. I don't need spelling suggestions or any spelling-correcting features. Just a simple function that takes a string and returns a boolean value.

I could do this easily with Python using PyEnchant, but it seems you have to compile the library yourself if you want to use it with MS Visual C++.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862699/c-spellchecker-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyEnchant is based on [Enchant](http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/), which is a C library providing C and C++ interfaces. So you can just use that for C++. The minimal example will be something like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

#include "enchant.h"
#include "enchant++.h"

int main ()
{
    try
        {
            enchant::Broker *broker = enchant::Broker::instance ();
        std::auto_ptr<enchant::Dict> dict (broker->request_dict ("en_US"));

            const char *check_checks[] = { "hello", "helllo" };
            for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof (check_checks) / sizeof (check_checks[0])); ++i)
        {
            printf ("enchant_dict_check (%s): %d\n", check_checks[i],
                dict->check (check_checks[i]) == false);
        }

    } catch (const enchant::Exception &) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For more examples/tests, see their [SVN repository](http://www.abisource.com/viewvc/enchant/trunk/).

Comment: This is what I'd like to do, but I have practically no experience using external libraries in C++. Since they don't provide any binaries, do I have to include all the Enchant files in my project, or can I use the .dlls included with PyEnchant somehow?

Comment: @Nicholas: Looks like it comes with MSVC project files. you could use those to build the library, then reference it from your own code. Simply including all the files in your own project usually works as well

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement such function on your own, you'll need a database to query in order to find out whether a given word is valid (usually a plain text file is enough, like `/usr/share/dict/words` on Linux).

Otherwise you could rely upon a third party spellcheck library that does just that.

Answer (score 2):

You could take one of the GNU dictionaries out there (like `/usr/share/dict/words` as mentioned) and build it into an appropriate data structure that'll give you fast lookup and membership checking depending on your performance needs, something like a [directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) or even just a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a word list, for starters. ([/usr/share/dict/words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)) maybe?)

You should read your word list into a `std::set`. Then a correct-spelling test consists simply of checking all the user input words for whether or not they are in the set.

Answer (score -1):

```
bool spell_check(std::string const& str)
{
  std::cout << "Is '" << str << "' spelled correctly? ";
  std::string input;
  std::getline(input);

  return input[0] == 'y' || input[0] == 'Y';
}
```

Comment: A snarky, but correct given the specifications, response to the question.

Comment: What is it about the function you don't understand?

Comment: Why are you checking the first character? Is there any rule that tells "words are correctly spelled if it starts with y"?